Troubleshooting ST-238R and WD1002A controller card
Having a cryptic issue with this pair of hardware.  Scenario:

Amstrad PC1640DD (manual here) with one floppy long since swapped out for an HDD.  Exact controller card is WD1002A-27X (board photos here), ROM at (seg) C800h, IO 320-323h, DMA 3.  Haven't yet found a detailed programming or OEM manual for this exact board, nor any support programs, so I don't know what diagnostics are available.
Historically speaking, the drive worked with, and was formatted by, this card in particular.  Am aware of card differences. (Actually, I think this drive went from ST to WD controllers at some point, years and years ago. Young me managed to figure out the low level format command just fine.  I didn't make any hardware changes since then.)
Somewhere along the way (moving, sitting on the shelf, etc.), they stopped working.
The exact boot message is "Insert a SYSTEM disk into drive A / Then press any key_".  Booting MS-DOS, it says C: is an "invalid drive specification".  INT 13h calls generally return errors for drive spec 80h (first HDD).  So the BIOSs are failing or not enumerating the HDD at some level.
I later installed a XT-IDE and CF card, and the 360k 5-1/4" floppy drive still works fine; the system is usable.  But I am curious what's on the HDD (I never made full backups of it).  Specifically, I am not interested in low-level formatting just to get it working again (if that would do it at all, which I'm starting to suspect it wouldn't).
I have tested the drive independently, by poking and reading ST506 signals.  It seems fine?  I can't decode the raw RLL of course, but the pattern seems to change from cylinder to cylinder (it seeks fine).
The drive POST itself has one quirk, possibly due to age and the mechanism; it chugs a lot during startup (homing).  Seems like the stepper moves too much (backstop (rubber bumper?) too soft, or dislodged or missing?), so it thinks homing failed, and keeps on chugging.  Eventually it times out and reports \READY.  (Seeking, and track 0 detect, seem to be working fine.)

I don't have a logic analyzer, or breakout for the ST506 interface, but I can probe several signals at a time with the oscilloscope, or do anything on the PC -- from IN/OUT, to INT 13h calls, to diagnostics programs if available.
Other things to check include power quality / ripple (PSU may have failing electrolytics, want to replace those at some point anyway), or swapping out the card (I don't have a replacement/alternate on hand, though).  Or drive swap for that matter (given a known-good one), but again, don't have one.
A visual inspection of the card doesn't show any obvious failures, like cracked components or solder joints, shorts between pads, or broken traces.  Invisible failures like ESD damage, or general component decay (under the package, without visible lead corrosion), are always possible, but seems unlikely.
Testing:
On normal boot (from floppy), 0040:0075h reads 01h.  Running:
MOV AH,14
INT 13
INT 3
MOV AH,10
MOV DL,80
INT 13
INT 3
MOV AH,0
MOV DL,80
INT 13
INT 3
MOV AH,11
MOV DL,80
INT 13
INT 3

in DEBUG, stepping over the INT 3s, shows:

AH=14h: carry set, AH=1 (invalid function/parameter?)
AH=10h: no carry, AH=0
AH=0: no carry, AH=0
AH=11h: no carry, AH=0

Clearing 40:0075h, I get:

AH=14h: no carry, AH=0
AH=10h: no carry, AH=0
AH=0: no carry, AH=0
AH=11h: no carry, AH=0

Also, 70:100h shows
10 99 12 00 C0
13 1A 03 00 C8 ...

so I gather the interrupt entry point is C800:031A. Which on disassembly, looks generally like an API, I'm not going to copy it down here of course.  Ah, and there's an INT 40 call in there, to chain to floppy or etc., which is a documented location/use.

Well, get a logic analyzer. I used one on a floppy drive to read one track and wrote a program to decode it.

This isn't a very helpful comment. LA or not, one still has to know what sequences the controller is producing. Back to square 1: programming/dev manual, or datasheets for the card chipset.

Do you have the ROM disassembly to check what might be possible reasons for it to decide there are no drives and not to hook INT13H? Or have you checked if it did hook INT13H? Have you tried to execute the ROM like it would be executed by ROM scan? Can you even see the ROM being there? The chugging may indicate the track0 sensor being bad, or out of alignment, if it does not detect it's already on track0.

I could disassemble it, but it's rather tedious to follow in DEBUG. I imagine it is hooking INT 13h, but that's a bit hard to know after MS-DOS loads (which hooks it). I don't know that the location of the original call is documented. (...Oh hey, Ralf Brown list says it may be at 70:100h?) How would I execute it as ROM, and what return values should I expect?

First guess is that the HDD just died - by accumulating too many read errors, by deadjusting something etc. So any way of capturing the data signals somewhere would help. Once they are captured, writing a little program to decode the headers and raw RLL to see what's wrong is not that hard (or maybe there's already useful software floating around somewhere). " it chugs a lot during startup (homing)." that's usually a sign the drive is trying to correct read errors (by trying to re-align the head). Another indication that the drive may have gone bad.

@dirkt It's not hunting during seeking, the controller (or firmware, as near as I can tell) doesn't even realize there's a drive attached. Like I said, the track 0 signal appears to be working. It's not even attempting to seek; INT 13h/AH=0Ch doesn't flash the activity LED and immediately returns error. If I knew what the controller was even looking for, I could probe for that...

Yes, "controller doesn't realize there's a drive" means something like it tried an initial read (probably for the bad sector list), and that failed so badly the firmware just gave up. Track 0 signal is hardware. In that state, it won't do anything. But if you can capture the track data during the initial read attempt, that would give an idea how bad it is. Apparently people can collect flux samples, so somehow that should be possible...

And RLL coding rules can e.g. be found here.

I happen to have that exact same drive/controller combination, and already did some disassembly on the BIOS. If I understand the POST correcty, it should display the error code 1701 if no drive is detected. The number of detected drive is stored at 40:75. You can set it to 01 from 00 to enable BIOS access to the controller. Then try running function 14 (controller diag), 10 (test drive ready), 00 (reset) and 11 (recalibrate). If those four calls pass, the drive should also be picked up by the POST.

C800:031A matches the ROM dump I have. That's great. The reason for your failure of the first AH=14 call is likely that the HDD BIOS only responds to the call if DL=80, which you didn't set yet. The reason the BIOS responds with 40:75 being zero seems to be an off-by-one bug 342..34c. So we are back to square one: The BIOS reports that the drive is present (40:75 is 1 after POST), reports the controller passes diagnostics, the drive is ready and can be recalibrated. What error code do you get when trying INT 13 AX=201, CX=1, DX=80? (Read MBR)?

Also try AX=401 to run a non-DMA command trying to read a sector to remove broken DMA handing from the possible points of failures. OTOH, you can use AH=0E/0F (read/write buffer) to verify DMA operation without involving the drive.

@MichaelKarcher RBIL says AH=14h doesn't depend on DL, but come to think of it, there's a DL check early in the handler which probably matters. Aha, that indeed returns AH=0, NC. AH=0Eh deposits a rising bit sequence (I recall coming across something like this in a WD OEM manual). AH=2 returns AH=40h (seek error?).

I have disassemblies of both the x86 host BIOS and the microcontroller code for a very similar WD controller found on bitsavers. I will try to check where error 40 originates. "Seek error" combined with the seeking issues during the drive POST on the other hand start to look like a drive fault, though.

The BIOS disassembly seems to take the 40H directly from the WD1015. Too bad my better understood WD1015 disassemblies (WD1015-PL, WD1015-CL) are obviously from non-WD11C00-based controllers, and the WD1015-14 disassembly doesn't seem to have logic to return "0x40".
Interestingly, the BIOS function 01 requests some status from the 1015 and translates it, whereas the other BIOS functions do not translate the status byte. You might want to check what function 01 returns after the failed read.

Look at this: https://www.minuszerodegrees.net/manuals/Western%20Digital/WD1002S-WX2%20-%20OEM%20Manual.pdf - this describes a lot on what's going on in those controllers!

Assuming I missed how the error code gets translated, and 40H is a translated Int13 error code, the controller error code (as in the WD1002S-WX2 manual) would be 02, 08 or 15 (obtained from the WD1002A-27X BIOS translation code at 751..7D1). 02 and 08 would also appear on "test drive ready" or "recalibrate", so the error code is 15, indicating that the expected sector ID header could not be found, either due to a damaged track, damaged head or head misalignment. Try reading other sectors.

Note that the ST-238R uses buffered seeks. This means the seek pulses get sent in very quick sequence to the drive, and the drive then seeks "in the background". The duration of transferring the seek pulses may be short enough that you don't notice the drive LED lighting up. Only when you issue a "test drive ready" afterwards, you get to know whether the seek is completed (yielding "seek error / 40H" until "seek complete" is active).

@TimWilliams please ignore my claims that AH on READ is directly the status byte from the controller. I indeed misunderstood the BIOS code. AH on READ is correctly generated, as laid out in my answer, which is meant to supercede all my comments on the question.

The WDC XT hard drive controllers try to mostly imitate the interface of the original Xebec IBM XT hard drive controllers, although they have an entirely different architecture.
A quite comprehensive description of the architecture of the WDC-1002S-WX2 hard drive controller has been scanned. While that controller is MFM, whereas the WD1002A-27X is RLL, it has a very similar architecture, based on the WD11C00-17 host interface chip, a WD1015-based controller chip (which is just a mask programmed 8048), and a WD1010-(derived) hard drive interface chip. The WD5011 on the WD1002A-27X is programmed quite similarly to the WD1010 (see footnote 1).
All the 8048 variants that are used as front-end for the WD1010 are called WD1015 by western digital. The number at the end can make a big difference. The WD1002S-WX2 datasheet specifically mentions the WD1015-14, for which you can find a disassembly. That specific variant has 17 sectors / track hardcoded, so it is not usable on RLL controllers, but as it interfaces to the same kind of chips (WD11C00 on the host side, WD1010-like chip on the drive side), that listing can give you a good idea on how the chip operates - you "just" have to understand what the code means. Luckily, you don't really have to, because the WD1002S-WX2 OEM manual describes the behaviour of that controller quite well.
I looked at the WD1002(A)-27X BIOS (I own the WD1002-27X with the extra jumpers, but our BIOSes seem to be very similar or identical), the BIOS checks the "status byte" returned by the WD1015. Assuming the WD1015-48 on the WD1002A-27X behaves similarly to the WD1015-14, that status byte is the SCSI-inspired byte having bit 1 set in case of error, and having bit 5 indicate what drive was selected. The error bit is tested in the function that handles the completion status (at C800:0812..0834) and returned (inverted) in the zero flag. If the call to 0812 performed from 074A sees the zero flag clear (an error occurred), it falls through into the handler that is also called for AH=01 (at C800:0751). To find more information about the nature of the error, it sends a dedicated command to read error info (which has command code 3, probably not accidentally identical to SCSI "request sense", see footnote 2), which will return a WD proprietary error code. The translation table in the WD1002A-27X BIOS fits to the documented codes in the WD1002S-WX2 datasheet, so there is no reason to believe these codes changed.
As you observed error code 40H when trying to read a sector, I can conclude from the error code translation table that the raw error code by the WD1015 controller was one of

02: Seek complete not seen within 1 second when trying to perform the next operation on the drive.
08: Seek complete not seen on "test drive ready". This code is actually not an "error", but describes the kind of non-readyness of the drive
15: "Seek error": Actually, the description of that code looks very much like "sector not found" instead of "seek error", as it means that the sector header for the requested sector could not be found during multiple revolutions of the drive.

As you observe no error on test drive ready or recalibrate, I am quite confident that your issue is actually caused by error code 15h. You likely can find the raw error code at 40:0042 in the BIOS data area after the failed read call. In case the code is actually 15h when trying to read the MBR, this means either that the read head is not located on track zero, even though TRK000 got asserted, or that the sector ID of the MBR is damaged.
You can try to read other sectors, hoping that your issue is an isolated failure on reading the MBR or track 0 as whole, but possibly seeking on that drive failed entirely and you might constantly be off the correct cylinder.
A possible cause for your issue is that the ST-238R does not auto-park, so if you powered down the system after DOS updated some info in the FAT, the head might have crashed into track 0 and damaged it.

1: Actually, it seems XTA/ATA, heavily influenced by Western Digital is just tying their WD1010-family type hard drive controllers directly to the ISA bus instead of using an 8048 processor to translate the Xebec protocol to their native protocol.
2: There are even more resemblences of the Xebec protocol to SCSI, like read and write having command codes 08 and 0A respectively, commands being transferred as a "command block" byte-by-byte to the controller, test drive ready and recalibrate being 00 and 01.

Returning to this, now that PC is operating again (inspected the power supply, capacitors, solder joints, etc.); 40:42h contains 95h after a failed read (carry, AH=40h). More or different bits used? Overwritten later/elsewhere? Do you know if the recovery (microstep) mode is supported by this controller? Is there any way to force the controller to step? Is any further recovery going to require a low level (i.e. logic capture + decoding) method then?

I forgot to mention that the top bit indicates "address of affected sector is available". So this means "error 15h while reading sector ..." (sector address is encoded in the subsequent bytes). Error 15 is generated if (a) The WD5011 returns "sector ID not found" or (b) the cylinder number in a valid sector header mismatches or (c) the head number in a valid sector header mismatches.

After recalibration, the controller will perform a "scan ID" command before trying to read/write. This command can result in "sector ID not found" if no valid sector ID is detect at the current head position (case (a)), but after successful execution, the obtained ID is verified against the expected cylinder/head number, possibly triggering causes (b) and (c) for that error code.

In case track 0 is damaged, try reading a sector on cylinder 100. If the drive and controller is operating properly, this should cause 100 seek pulses to be output to seek the drive to cylinder 100 before the controller tries to verify the correct seek operation using "scan ID". If it does not cause a seek, the seeking is probably aborted because "drive ready" was deasserted or "write fault" was asserted when the controller tried to start seeking.

The controller does not support microstepping (it can not, as the stepper controller is part of the drive, not of the WD1002-27X). Also, you can not ask the controller to issue seek pulses in any other way than sending a seek command - which will get rejected if "drive not ready" or "write fault".

"can not" -- the "recovery" signal I mean, which apparently activates microstepping on these drives? Maybe I misunderstood that section. (There's also a related jumper on the drive, but if the controller doesn't know that's there, it won't know to send X times more pulses and seek would fail anyway. Or does it work the other way, telling the controller that was asserted? Hmph, need to recheck the doc.)

@TimWilliams Oh, sorry, I didn't know that the ST-238R includes a recovery mode. I don't expect the WD1002-27X to be able to activate the recovery line at the interface. Recovery is on pin 16 of the control cable, see http://ftpmirror.your.org/pub/misc/bitsavers/pdf/seagate/mfm/ST-412HP_Comp_Design_198404.pdf - you might want to check whether that pin is connected to any logic on the board. I don't have the physical hardware at hand at the moment to check myself.

Hmm, seeking doesn't necessarily fail, but reads from high cylinders don't seem to succeed in any case (not for lack of trying, the call takes a moment to return). Drive is in the PC so I can't see if the motor has moved, doesn't sound like it though. Still basic AH=40h "seek failed" message. 40:40-50h shows 00 00 95 01 41 00 00 07-02 03 50 00 00 10 00 00 if that's any help. I'll have to pull the board to check, but from the photo, it seems plausible there's no trace to pin 16.

The dump you sent reads as "seek error while trying to read CHS=256/1/1". As internally the WD1002 controllers use zero-based sector numbers, it could mean 256/1/2 as well. Assuming the firmware of the WD1002A-27X behaves the same way as the WD1002S-WX2, the controller should always send seek pulses (making the drive move) when trying to seek to a different cylinder, unless the drive reports a fatal error. If the drive does return a fatal error (not ready or write fault), the return code would be that status, not "seek error". So I guess if the stepper doesn't move when trying to seek...

,,, something is clearly wrong with the drive handling the steps. If the drive is at some end stop, you might want to test whether the seek direction signal is reaching the drive.
